# Why are the Nac Mag Feegle Scottish?

Tags: terry-pratchett, discworld

In *The Wee Free Men* - and other places where the Nac Mac Feegle are mentioned - they are quite obviously depicted as Scottish. The easiest example of that is their speech:

> "*Crivens! We wanna coo beastie, no' a ship beastie!*"
> "*Ach, one's as goo' as t'other! C'mon, lads, a' grab aholt o' a leg!*"
> "*Aye, all the coos are inna shed, we tak what we can!*"
> <sub>*The Wee Free Men*, chapter 3: "Hunt the Hag"</sub>

They also wear kilts, are red-haired, and get drunk a lot - all of which are associated with the Scots.

Is there any particular reason why the Nac Mag Feegle are Scottish? (In-universe, it doesn't look like anyone else speaks or behaves like them (including the Fairy Queen (or the "Quin")), but I haven't read all of the books yet.) Out of universe, what purpose does them being Scottish serve for the story?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you're looking for here. The obvious answer for what them being Scottish adds to the story is **humour**, just the chance to include some comically caricaturised Caledonians. Are you hoping for some *plot* relevance, some reason why stereotypical Scots were needed to drive the story? (If you didn't know, even the name "Wee Free" [screams Scottishness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wee_Free).)

Comment: I got a bit tired of Pratchett's humour, since he tended to recycle the same old jokes, but now I want to read him again.

Comment: Anything using "wee" sounds Scottish to me :). I'm looking for how their Scottishness affects the story; humor is certainly one answer (and being obvious doesn't necessarily make it a bad answer), but I'm also looking for any other ways in which specifically the Scottishness actually was relevant or necessary (or affected the story in other ways).